# How to test styled-components with Jest in React-Native project?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, styled-components

In my project, I have a component styled with styled-components.I want to test it using jest:

```
describe('<Button/> tests', () => {
    it('should render button', () => {
        const testingComponent =  renderer.create(<Button/>);
    })
});
```

This code fails with:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: _styledComponents.default.View is not a function

      1 | import styled from 'styled-components';
      2 |
    > 3 | const Container = styled.View`
        |                          ^
      4 |   flex: 1;
      5 |   align-self: center;
      6 | `;
```

SO jest does not recognize `styled.View` and I don't know why. What I'm doing wrong and how can I test my components, which I styled with styled-components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to avoid such errors is needed to specify styled components in a such way:

```
const Container = styled(View)
```

This syntax  helped me